# Grails Unit Test does not work when dependency inject is necessary

Tags: unit-testing, grails, dependency-injection, spock

I am trying to run my unit tests in **Grails 4.0.3** through the command **grails test-app**.

Unfortunately I am in trouble with dependency injection.

I have basically two test cases. The first one does not work with the response **No GORM implementations configured. Ensure GORM has been initialized correctly** It seems that PidService is not correctly injected.

To demonstrate my suspicion I created a private method which only throws an exception, to be invoked in the second test case. So, I invoked that method in the second one and it worked as expected. The exception was correctly catched and I could verify that the message is correct.

```
package br.gov.cmb.pid.tests

import br.gov.cmb.pid.services.PidService
import grails.testing.services.ServiceUnitTest
import org.grails.web.json.JSONObject
import spock.lang.Specification


class PidIssuingSpec extends Specification implements ServiceUnitTest<PidService> {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }


    def "Test that injection is not working"() {
        given:
        JSONObject wrongPidIssuingDocument = new JSONObject()

        when:
        service.buildPidIssuingOrder(wrongPidIssuingDocument)

        then:
        def e = thrown(Exception)
        e.message == "Register number is mandatory."
    }


    def "Test that works because no injection is necessary"(){
        when:
        dispException()

        then:
        def e = thrown(Exception)
        e.message == "Register number is mandatory."
        println(e.message)

    }

    private void dispException(){
        throw new Exception("Register number is mandatory.")
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message you have shown indicates that GORM is involved but there isn't any code shown which is obviously GORM.  Can you share a sample project which demonstrates the behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Grails Unit Test does not work when dependency inject is necessary

In general unit tests that require dependency injection is supported.

See the **Modifying the Application Context** section at https://testing.grails.org/2.4.1/guide/index.html#unitTesting.  That demonstrates how to add beans to the context in a unit test so they may be injected.  For example, you could do this:

```
Closure doWithSpring() {{ ->
    // create a bean named "someService" which
    // is an instance of SomeService.
    // the someService bean may be injected into the 
    // the class under test
    someService(SomeService)
}}
```

At https://github.com/grails/grails-testing-support/blob/9f782ff3b911919e421440feb8a2e4736c6aced6/examples/demo33/src/test/groovy/demo/ReportingServiceSpec.groovy is a working example:

```
package demo

import grails.testing.services.ServiceUnitTest
import spock.lang.Specification

class ReportingServiceSpec extends Specification implements ServiceUnitTest<ReportingService> {

    Closure doWithSpring() {{ ->
        someHelper RushHelper
    }}

    void "test dependency injection"() {
        expect:
        service.retrieveSomeNumber() == 2112
    }
}

class RushHelper implements MathHelper {

    @Override
    int getSomeNumber() {
        2112
    }
}
```

Notice that the `service` being tested is the `ReportingService`.  The `RushHelper` is being injected into that service to support the test.